# toTitleCase javascript edge case

Tags: javascript, regex

**Scenario:**

I have a typical *toTitleCase()* JavaScript function w/RegEx that I am using for a single text field for a person first and last name.

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
     return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}
```

**Problem**

As indicated - in this case, I am using this function for a first and last name. Accordingly - there will be the potential for an individual's name to have more than one upper case character. e.g.: James O'Mally or Robert McNally. Unfortunately, the above JavaScript function will return James O'mally or Robert Mcnally.

I was hoping some awesome Stackoverflow contributor(s) could provide a RegEx solution that would take this edge case into consideration and leave an existing uppercase value in the middle of string intact.

Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: seems like you could just replace "O'(\w)" and "Mc(\w)" at the end...

Comment: @dandavis: Thanks for the input - it is certainly a good point; however, the enumerations of these occurrences is unpredictable. Mc and O where simply examples. There are a variety of names - particularly last names that have this pattern. e.g. Oscar De LaHoya or William DuBouis

Comment: As it is, the question is too broad. There is no way we can write a regex without knowing what it should match.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `/\b[a-z]/g` is what you are looking for. It will upper case any letter (a-z) after a word boundary.

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
     return str.replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (txt) { 
       return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); 
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Gaby... I was not actually attempting to introduce an upper case, simply preserve an upper case value if found in the middle of a word. I believe nhahtdh is probably correct implying the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

@nhahtdh - It sounds like you may be right about this problem being to broad to answer. Perhaps I will forego the RegEx and write a custom formatter that takes this pattern into consideration.  Thanks for everyone's help